# Jquery/Javascript, dynamic array sorting with index

Tags: javascript, jquery

i have a dynamic array as below which will display in the Hightchat and using date as a index for the same
[34,23,44,34,0,0,23,23,40,0,0,0,0,0,10]
after this will sort the array and get first 10 highest list of array as below
[44,40,34,34,23,23,23,10,0,0]
issues i am facing here is for repeated numbers like (34,34,23,23....) i am getting same date as a index for example( consider for 34 i have and a date 23/04/2017 as a index.. same date is displayed for both the number(34,34).. 
kindly help me out to get the respective index for repeated values in an array..
please reply back if you need more info

Comment: So you do not want the repeated value on the array in top 10 highest list after sorting?

Comment: Could you please post a proper input and output scenario so we know where exactly you are stuck with and help you accordingly?

Comment: So do you want to remove the repeated number from array,It should be contain only once.

Comment: input - [34,23,44,34,0,0,23,23,40,0,0,0,0,0,10] and the index would be as follows[23/04/2017,24/04/2017,25/04/2017,26/04/2017,27/04/2017,28/04/2017,29/04/2017,30/04/2017,01/05/2017,02/05/2017,03/05/2017,04/05/2017,05/05/2017,06/05/2017,07/05/2017] out put - array list as like[44,40,34,34,23,23,23,10,0,0] and index should be[25/04/2017,01/05/2017,23/04/2017,26/04/2017,24/04/2017,29/04/2017,30/04/2017.....] i need repeated number with there index.

Comment: @Guru See the solution

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var A = [34,23,44,34,0,0,23,23,40,0,0,0,0,0,10];
var B = ['23/04/2017','24/04/2017','25/04/2017','26/04/2017','27/04/2017','28/04/2017','29/04/2017','30/04/2017','01/05/2017','02/05/2017','03/05/2017','04/05/2017','05/05/2017','06/05/2017','07/05/2017'];

var all = [];

for (var i = 0; i < B.length; i++) {
  all.push({ 'A': A[i], 'B': B[i] });
 }

all.sort(function(a, b) {
   return b.A - a.A;
 });

 A = [];
 B = [];

 for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
  A.push(all[i].A);
  B.push(all[i].B);
 }    

 console.log(A, B);
```

This solution can solve your problem please have a look on these It will gives you the result which expected.

I am sorting using hash so that each key have correct value.